# Getting string from AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've been searching around on google for a while, trying to find an easy way to make AJAX work. I've found some things but so far I haven't been lucky with getting them to work.
I would like to get a string from a PHP file called 'serverstatus.php'.
The string is currently outputted on the serverstatus page like this:
"Online:0:20 Offline"
Explanation:
There are two servers, the first one is online has 0 out of 20 clients.
The second one is offline.

What i want it to do is load these values via AJAX, then split them with " " then split each of those values i got by ":".
That should give me everyhting i want.

The code i have to get the string is this:

```
<head>
<script>
    var someVar;
    $.ajax({url: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/int/serverstatus.php', success: function(ajaxResponse) {
        someVar = ajaxResponse;
        document.write(someVar);
    }});
</script>
</head>
```

NOTE: I want the code to be called as soon as the page is starting to load.

EDIT:
I think the problem is that it's not getting any values from the status page.
Also, the values on the status page are loaded from an MySQL server, so it takes about 1-3 seconds to show up.

Comment: Don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: document.write(someVar.data)

Comment: What is the question? I don't see any splitting going on in your code. `Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself.`

Comment: It doesn't appear that [`jquery.js`](http://jquery.com/download/) is being included before trying to use [`jQuery.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: I tried including jquery.js, but it printed it onto the website instead.

Comment: From the comments posted below some of the answers it is clear that your Ajax call is not returning a string in the format that you describe. Please add `console.log(ajaxResponse);` as the first line of your success function, open your browser's console (F12 in Chrome or IE) and run your code to see what you get. (Or if you can't manage that for some reason use `alert(ajaxResponse);`.

Comment: Wow, somethings definetly wrong, it printed all the text inside index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will run as soon as the page has loaded and split your strings. The data will then be put into the div with the ID - response_container

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    var someVar;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'serverstatus.php',
        success: function(ajaxResponse) {

            var data = ajaxResponse.split(" ")[0].split(":");
            currentClients = data[1];
            maxClients = data[2];

            $("#response_container").append('Clients: ' + currentClients + ', Max: ' + maxClients);

        }
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="response_container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: From the question: "NOTE: I want the code to be called as soon as the page is starting to load."

Comment: I tried doing this and it tells me this: "Clients: undefined, Max: undefined".

Comment: After adding the path i think it's supposed to use, it doesn't display anything.

Comment: In your example it looks like you added some PHP in the javascript code without using the PHP open / close tags. Have you done that again?

Comment: Uhm, dumb question, but where..? (Probably)

Comment: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/int/serverstatus.php'. Did you mean:- '<?php echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; ?>/inc/int/serverstatus.php'

Comment: You're right, after adding that the old problem came back, giving me "Clients: undefined, Max: undefined".

Comment: type that URL into the browser and see what's displayed - can you show a copy of that? It may not be formatted correctly.

Comment: This is what is on the whole page: "Online:0:20 Offline"

Comment: There's something wrong with the path to the serverstatus page. When using "http://127.0.0.1/inc/int/serverstatus.php" instead, it worked, but i do not want to use that. Any reason why i must use that?

Answer (score 1):

> *"then split them with " " then split each of those values i got by ":"*

So what's the problem? Implementing exactly what you described is simple:

```
var tmp = ajaxResponse.split(" ")[0].split(":");
var currentClients = tmp[1];
var maxClients = tmp[2];
```

...though if the string that comes back from the server is in the wrong format you'll obviously have a problem so you may want to do the `.split()` operations separately.

Or you could just use a regex instead of `.split()`:

```
var currentClients,
    maxClients,
    matches = ajaxResponse.match(/(\d+):(\d+)/);
if (matches){
   currentClients = matches[1];
   maxClients = matches[2];
} else {
   // response was in the wrong format, so do something else
}
```

Comment: Just send back JSON from the server so you don't have to do post processing on the client.

Comment: @azizpunjani - Yes, that's what I'd do. But if the PHP can't be changed for some reason (perhaps the response string is displayed as-is by some other page that calls it) then it's easy enough to extract the values with regex (or `.split()`).

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var someVar;
$.ajax({url: $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/inc/int/serverstatus.php', success:
function(ajaxResponse)
{
     var array = ajaxResponse.split(" ");
     for(var i in array)
     {
        var subArray = array[i].split(":");
        if(array[i] === "Offline")
            document.body.innerHTML += "Server "+i+" is offline.<br/>";
        else
        {
            document.body.innerHTML += "Server "+i+" has "+subArray[1]+" out of "+subArray[2]+" clients online.<br/>";
        }
     }
}
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VusC8/

Comment: I tried this, doesn't give me anything. Is there anything in particular that could be keeping me from using AJAX?

Comment: Check your developer tools, your developer tools tell you precisely what's wrong if something is wrong.

Comment: Developer tools? I'm using Notepad++ if that's what you mean.

Comment: @9903286 your jQuery may not be working correctly. Also, sometimes AJAX fails, so it could be triggering an error instead of your `success` handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str="Online:0:20 Offline";
var n=str.split(":");
```

n will be an array of your values.

[see more about the split function here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

edit: i think i miss interpreted whats going wrong maybe, can you update your input string and what you want as an output